# Fourier transformation of $\sin(ax)\exp(\frac{-x^2}{2})$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have been trying to calculate the Fourier transformation of $$\sin(ax)\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)$$ using $$\int_{\Bbb R} \cos(ax)\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)dx = \sqrt{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{-a^2}{2}\right)$$, but haven't been able to succeed. I've mainly tried using integration by parts, but I don't feel like I'm getting somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\sin(ax) =\frac{1}{2i}(e^{aix}-e^{-aix})$$

Let $b= \pm a$ then using the parity argument of sine and cosine we get  $$\mathcal{F}\left(e^{ibx}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)\right)(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\Bbb R}e^{i(b-y)x}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)dx \\=
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\Bbb R}\cos(\color{red}{b-y)}x)\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)dx =\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-(b-y)^2}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: I've tried using the hint and manipulating the exponentials to get a combination of two $cos$, but it doesn't seem to work out. Not sure how I should use the second tip.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{R} exp(i<x,y>)f(x)dx$

Comment: I tried getting $cos(ax)$ in complex exponential form. So far, I have this: $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{R} \frac{1}{2} exp(ix(y+a)-\frac{x^2}{2}) - exp(ix(y-a)-\frac{x^2}{2})dx$

Comment: Been trying to add terms and distract the same terms, but don't seem to get anywhere...

Comment: @User5465404560498408406 see the edit

Comment: Knowing the solution of my question, how should I then calculate the Fourier transformation of $cos(ax)exp(\frac{-x^2}{2})$? Tried using some of the derivative formulas for Fourier integrals, but they don't work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-ikx} = e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}-\frac{k^2}{2}}$ for $u = x+ik$. Then you can write $\sin(ax)$ as $\sin(au-b)$ and expand using the sum formula. You will have two term with $\sin(au)$ and $\cos(au)$. The $\sin$ term should be zero by symmetry.

You may have to integrate off the real axis.

Comment: Could you specify why the $sin$ term is zero?

Comment: $sin(-a)=-sin(a)$, so if you break the domain to positive and negative real parts, the two parts should cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

This problem hinges on "complex" integrals having a zero part due to an odd integrand. We want to compute a Fourier transform, the imaginary number $iS(a,\,k):=\int \sin ax\exp-\frac{x^2}{2}i\sin kx dx$, from the real number $C(a,\,k):=\int \cos ax\exp-\frac{x^2}{2}\cos kx dx$. In particular $C\pm S=\int\cos(a\mp k)x\exp -\frac{x^2}{2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\exp-\frac{(a\mp k)^2}{2}$. Thus $iS=i\sqrt{8\pi}\exp-\frac{a^2+k^2}{2}\sinh ak$.

Comment: This is very creative.